# XPath: Select first element in each row which matches a specific class

Tags: xpath, import.io

Is it possible to select the first element in each row which matches a specific class? This is the HTML structure at the moment.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <article>
      <time class="published-date"></time> 
      <p>Text</p>
    </article>
  </li>
  <li>
    <article>
      <time class="published-date"></time>
      <p>Text</p>
    </article>
  </li>
<ul>
```

I was wondering what would be the best and most specific query string in terms of getting the time element with the class `published-date` in each row?

Answer (score 2):

If there are more `time` elements with `class="published-date"` in every row, you need to use indexing (1-based):

```
//ul/li/article/time[@class = "published-date"][1]
```

If there is only a single `time` element in every row, simply do:

```
//ul/li/article/time[@class = "published-date"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the XPath selector....

```
//time[@class="published-date"]
```

...will select all `time` nodes with the class `published-date`. [XPathFiddle](http://xpathfiddle.net/T23WVL)